# отличаются шрифты на mac и на windows

Tags: html, шрифты

шрифты отличаются смотря на какой ос зайти на сайт.
[image: на винде]

[image: на маке]

получается что если бы был в тексте заглавные буквы, то на маке шрифт прижат к верхнему краю, а на винде по центру. есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы там и там текст выглядел одинаково?

Comment: В одном случае высота строки с учетом заглавной буквы, во втором без учёта. Попробуйте line-heigth зафиксировать в пикселях